# Unable to get content to display on localbrowser using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am currently trying to create a website using React, but as the title states, I can't seem to get my content to appear in the local browser and I'm unsure where I went wrong.

[Image of localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enKB6.jpg)

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css"
import Layout from "./src/components/Layout/Layout";

function App() {
  return <Layout />
}

export default App;
```

Routers.js:

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Shop from '../pages/Shop';
import Cart from '../pages/Cart';
import Product_Dets from '../pages/Product_Dets';
import Checkout from '../pages/Checkout';
import Login from '../pages/Login';
import Signup from '../pages/Signup';

const Routers = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="shop" element={<Shop />} />
      <Route path="shop/:id" element={<Product_Dets />} />
      <Route path="cart" element={<Cart />} />
      <Route path="checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
      <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="signup" element={<Signup />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default Routers;
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "remixicon/fonts/remixicon.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Layout.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import Footer from "../Footer/Footer";
import Routers from "../../routers/Routers";

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div>
        <Routers />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

I have tried updating react and looked up similar issues on stackoverflow but unable to find the solution.

Image of console

[image]

Comment: The stacktrace is saying the the `Routes` component rendered by `Routers` rendered by `Layout` rendered by `App` ***doesn't*** have a router/routing context provided to it. According to your code though there's clearly a `BrowserRouter` wrapping `App`. Are you sure you saved the file change and ensured the browser is running the latest version of your code? I don't see any issue with the code you have here.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason why a blank page renders is that an error exists in the code snippet. Please check the information provided by the debug tool of the browser.
According to the part `import Layout from "./src/components/Layout/Layout";`  of the App.js file, I guess you possibly placed the index.js and App.js in the root folder instead of the src folder. The app could not find the entry point to start, so the page went blank.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have tried placing the index.js file in the src folder, but unfortunately the page was still blank.

Comment: Have you also placed the App.js in src folder? If you did, please make sure all paths inside import statements are correct. For example, ```import Layout from "./src/components/Layout/Layout";``` is not accurate. I am not sure which building tool that you are using: create-react-app or vite or something else, but I am a little confused why you changed the initial location of index.js file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `Routes` component. You haven't defined what react is supposed to render when the path is `/` or `localhost:19007`.

So to solve this, you need to define a new route whose path is "/" in your Routers component :

```
const Routers = () => {
return(
 <Routes>
    {/* add below line */}
    <Route path="/" element={<div>Homepage</div>} />
    
    <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="shop" element={<Shop />} />
    <Route path="shop/:id" element={<Product_Dets />} />
    <Route path="cart" element={<Cart />} />
    <Route path="checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
    <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="signup" element={<Signup />} />
  </Routes>
)};
```

Edit: You can use [Navigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) component to redirect users to `localhost:19007/home` when they visit your site at `localhost:19007`.

```
<Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="home" />} />
```

Comment: No, not having a `"/"` route path would cause a different error/warning. It's not the problem OP is describing.

Comment: @DrewReese Shouldn't we specify the logic to render on root path. Would not including what to render on " / " path, classify as a bug? Is there something in React Router v6 to handle that.

Comment: And the only other solution to above problem I can think of is using `Navigate`:   <Route exact path="/" element={<Navigate to="home" />} />

Comment: Yes, you *should* generally render a route for `path="/"` that renders *something*. That *something* can be any valid JSX, including the `Navigate` component.